I can't display the camera image in Telegram Web App. Everything is displayed correctly in the browser
Has anyone opened the user's camera in webapp? I'm trying to access the user's camera. Everything works in the browser, but through webapp it doesn't, it just doesn't see the camera, although I provided all permissions. Maybe someone has a template that can help me?


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Webcam Screenshot</title>
       <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
       <style>
          body{
             color: var(--tg-theme-text-color);
             background: var(--tg-theme-bg-color);
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: column;
             align-items: center;
             font-size: 18px;
          }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="usercard">
       </div>
       <video id="video" width="640" height="480"></video>
       <button id="screenshot-btn">Take Screenshot</button>
       <script>
          let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
          tg.expand();
          const video = document.getElementById('video');
          const screenshotBtn = document.getElementById('screenshot-btn');

          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(stream => {
                  video.srcObject = stream;
                  video.play();
              })
            .catch(error => {
                  console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);
              });

          screenshotBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
              const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
              canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
              const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              const screenshot = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',')[1];

              fetch('/screenshot', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({ screenshot: screenshot })
              })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error sending screenshot:', error));
          });

          tg.MainButton.text = "Send Screenshot";
          tg.MainButton.textColor = "#F55353";
          tg.MainButton.color = "#143F6B";

          Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', function(){
             tg.sendData("Screenshot sent!");
          });
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>

And the indicator shows that the camera is active, most likely a problem with the output, maybe someone knows what's wrong?

The issue might be telegram specific why not check Telegram's documentation or forums for any additional requirements or known issues regarding camera access in web apps.
